# How to differentiate two windows with the same name when creating a Macro

Tags: c#, .net, macros

I'm implementing a macro using C# allowing to click on a specified part of a window. But I've a problem when there is 2 windows with the same name.

I'm actually using the WindowsMouseManagement class to make it.

First I create a list with all the windows open :

```
WindowsMouseManagement.EnumWindows(new WindowsMouseManagement.EnumWindowsProc(WindowsMouseManagement.EnumTheWindows), IntPtr.Zero);

public static bool EnumTheWindows(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lParam)
        {
            int size = GetWindowTextLength(hWnd);
            if (size++ > 0 && IsWindowVisible(hWnd))
            {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(size);
                GetWindowText(hWnd, sb, size);
                //list = list + sb;
                list.Add(sb.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());

            }
            return true;
        }
```

And then, to get information about the window position, I'm using the "FindWindow" function , for example with the Calculator app :

```
WindowsMouseManagement.FindWindow(null, “calculator”)
```

So i was wondering if there is any other solution to get information about the window position using the PID or something else...

Comment: GetWindowRect() will take a HWND and return the position/size RECT.

Comment: How to get the good HWND when there is two windows with the same name ?

Comment: What criteria is it that makes you want one window instead of the other?

Comment: Ok, i'll clarify and Simplify my question, I have two window with the same name, how to get there 2 differents HWND ?

Comment: Your EnumTheWindows() callback gets given the HWND of each window so its in the same place as your fetching its text, store them both in your list?